# $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^5 \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \, dt - 1/x^4 + 1/3x^2)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^5 \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \,dt - 1/x^4 + 1/3x^2)$$

How to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Why would you write $1/x⁴$ instead of $1/x^4 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy ?

Comment: Do you see no typographical difference?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Does my writing the expression the way I wrote make it difficult to understand?

Comment: It might in some cases, for example if a far-sighted person is reading it without glasses. And the standard version looks better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series method.  As $x \to 0$ we have
\begin{align}
e^{-t^2} &= 1 -x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)
\\
\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\;dx &= x -\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{10}+o(x^5)
\\
\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\;dx &= \frac{1}{x^4} -\frac{1}{3x^2} 
+ \frac{1}{10}+o(1)
\\
\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\;dx -\frac{1}{x^4} + \frac{1}{3x^2}
&= \frac{1}{10}+o(1)
\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\;dx -\frac{1}{x^4} + \frac{1}{3x^2}\right)
&= \frac{1}{10}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: What is the Taylor polynomial of degree $4$ of $e^{-t^2}$ at $0$? Conceptually, it might help to put everything over the denominator $x^5$.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write the Taylor expansion for the $e^{-t^2}$:
$$e^{-t^2} = 1 - t^2 + \frac {t^4}2 - \frac {t^6}{3!}+...$$
Then integrate:
$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}{10}+...$$
Then the rest will be easy. After dividing by $x^5$, terms with any power of $x$ greater than $0$ will go to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. The expression under limit can be written as $$\frac{1}{x^5}\int_{0}^{x}(e^{-t^2}-1+t^2)\,dt$$ Let's put $u=t^5$ in the integral so that the above expression is transformed into $$\frac{1}{5x^5}\int_{0}^{x^5}(e^{-u^{2/5}}-1+u^{2/5})u^{-4/5}\,du$$ Putting $x^5=z$ and using FTC the limit of above expression is same as that of $$\frac{e^{-u^{2/5}}-1+u^{2/5}}{5u^{4/5}}$$ as $u\to 0$ (provided it exists). Replacing $u^{2/5}$ by $-t$ we see that the desired limit is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{e^{t} - 1-t}{t^2}$$ as $t\to 0$. It is easily seen either via L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series that the second fraction tends to $1/2$ and hence the desired limit is $1/10$.